# How to get value to description field defined for a property defined in loopback model

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, angular-loopback

I have the following model definition in a loopback project:
   `

```
{
  "name": "Program",
  "base": "PersistedModel",

  "properties": {
    "sId": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "length": 20
    },
    "Category": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 255,
      "description": "Category"
    },
    "ProgramName": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 255,
      "description": "Program Name"
    },
    "Program_Status": {
      "type": "string",
      "length": 255,
      "description": "Program Status"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "account": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Account",
      "foreignKey": "Account__c",
      "primaryKey": "sId"
    },
  },
  "methods": {}
}
```

`

I want to get value of description defined in field name in any other model. Is there anyway in loopback or express.js to get it?

Comment: what ? do you just want to access `description` property ?

Comment: I haven't seen that usage, but for a workaround solution, you can use "require" to include the json file of the model directly.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Actually, I need to define field label in description property.  I have used a similar approach in CakePHP model but couldn't find any way in loopback.

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible via `javascript` code. I'm afraid there isn't a way to access `json` files properties from another `json` file.

In **yourOtherModel.js**

```
module.exports = function(yourOtherModel){
var programProps = yourOtherModel.app.models.Program.properties;

//Your props
var programDescription = programProps.Category.description;
}
```